# locale issue with "python Requests library", how do I specify a request with a specific locale?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently using "Requests" and "BeautifulSoup" libraries to make http request to a url (http://www.flickr.com/) and extract data from the response html page.

The issue I encountered is,  I tried to extract data from the english version page only, but the chinese version page is returned based on my current locale.

Is there a way to configure the locale of the request?  in my case, english.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the Flickr API to get data from Flickr.

Comment: That depends on how Flickr determines the locale; if they use your ip address to give you an initial page you'll have to figure out how they use cookies or other means to record your preference, then replicate that in a `requests` request.

Comment: However, I believe Flickr has a API for you to use; it'll not be tied to any locale.

Comment: In any case, this isn't specific to `requests` or even Python, but entirely to the website.

Comment: Thanks Wooble, Martjin. flickr.com is just an example, I may need to extract data from other sites too.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how does Flickr recognises your locale.

If it takes care on which language is set in browser settings, you may need to include  englich in the list of acceptable languages how it is defined in HTTP specification.

To do that include "Accept-Language: en-US" in your headers.

For example, if you use requests.Session

```
session = Session()
session.headers.update({"Accept-Language": "en-US"})
... using session variable ...
```

Or if you use simple request change it to:

```
requests.get(...something..., headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US"})
```